# react-native-immediate-phone-call does't work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on creating a dialer in `React Native`. For dialing a call I was using `expo-linking` but that only opened default phone dialer. After researching here I found about about `react-native-immediate-phone-call` and tried it but I get no results. I installed it via `npm`, ejected project from expo a ran the app on a virtual phone but after I press the dial button I get an alert (so I now the function is working), but no dialing begins whatsoever.

```
<Pressable onPress={this.pressButton}>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} color={colorName} size={35} />
</Pressable>

pressButton = () => {
    this.setState({
      callValue: (call = !call)
    })
    Alert.alert(number)
    RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall(number);
  }
```

Could anyone please tell me why this is not working? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your phone permission for call :
In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your `android studio` project add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```